# Iron Claw mouse supprt

Tags: drivers, mouse, hardware

Good day Everyone,

I need help with getting my Corsair Ironclaw mouse to be fully functional on my ubuntu laptop, The R/L click buttons work as well as the DPI buttons but the rest do nothing currently.

Thank you,
Zach S.